# JFrame appears blank instead of showing UI

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jframe

I want to open MainWindow (that I created and added UI) after some time but Java opens blank default Jframe instead. How can I open already created window after splashscreen (`Start`)?

```
public class Start extends JFrame{
        private JPanel panel1;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Starting");
            frame.setContentPane(new Start().panel1);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            //frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            /*Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);*/

            frame.toFront();
            frame.pack();

            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    new MainWindows().setVisible(true);
                    frame.setVisible(false);

                    //System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            timer.start();

        }
```

---

### MainWindows.java

```
public class MainWindows extends JFrame{

    private JPanel panel;



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        boolean clicked = false;


        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Це перша вершія гри. Будь ласка, закрийте всі програми, щоб уникнути помилок.", "Увага!", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);


        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Flying");
        frame2.setContentPane(new MainWindows().panel);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        frame2.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame2.setUndecorated(true);
        frame2.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame2.setVisible(true);

        frame2.toFront();
        frame2.pack();
```

Comment: .. are you aware of the [`SplashScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) window?

Comment: General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) The current code seems to have a problem with the `panel1` attribute not being initialized. Make sure it is. 3) Change `timer.start();` to `timer.setRepeats(false); timer.start();`. This is an action that should only be performed a **single** time.

Comment: Why does `Start` extend `JFrame` ?

Comment: OK, deleted. Still not working.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. `frame2.setContentPane(panel);` Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: Glad to hear that this works, please make sure that you accept an answer in case anyone else has a similar issue.

Comment: sorry. undeleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainWindow` class has a static `main` method that's never invoked. It looks a lot like the code in there should have gone intoa constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two main methods in this program. I would suggest removing the main method from MainWindows.java and move the code from it into the MainWindows constructor. This will ensure that when you initialize the new MainWindows() object, everything in the new JFrame should be set up correctly.

Code in MainWindows.java:

```
    public MainWindows()
{

    boolean clicked = false;


    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Це перша вершія гри. Будь ласка, закрийте всі програми, щоб уникнути помилок.", "Увага!", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);


    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Flying");
    frame2.setContentPane(new MainWindows().panel);
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    frame2.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame2.setUndecorated(true);
    frame2.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame2.setVisible(true);

    frame2.toFront();
    frame2.pack();
```

Comment: Confirm Dialog does not disappear and when I comment it, the Start window doesn't disappear

Comment: I’m unsure what you mean, but it sounds like you’ve commented code out? My answer says to move code from the main method to the constructor and delete the main method rather than comment any code out.

Comment: I did this. Now I am talking about JOptionPane. It creates infinite of it.

Comment: This is probably due to your use of Timer. Follow the comment on your original question to ensure that this timer does not repeat as you only need the action to be run once.

Comment: It goes on loop to JOptionPane after frame2.setContentPane(new MainWindows().panel);

Comment: Yes, this is because of your Timer. Before you call timer.start(), call timer.setRepeats(false);